# What is the correct way to make the turbine blade geometry? What tools to use?

Tags: modeling, geometry

What's the best way to make a blade? I tried to come up with something with curves, but it turned out very poorly.
Src: https://thearchimedes.com/images/pdf/AWM%20brochure%20Respect%202023%20HQ%20compressed.pdf

[image: scheme]
[image: reference]